# ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier on Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi have the following query but when I am executing the query I am getting an error in oracle. The issue seems to be on the ORDER BY but I am not sure why there is an invalid identifier as my column is clearly present in the table. I am using sqldeveloper to execute the query.

> ORA-00904: "FINALRESULTS"."TESTTIME": invalid identifier

```
WITH tests AS (
 SELECT 
   t.place, 
   t.stationnr, 
   t.result, 
   i.type, 
   t.time,  
 FROM 
   result_test t 
   INNER JOIN result_ident i ON t.place= i.place
   JOIN stat_testplacegroup pg on pg.place = t.place 
   INNER JOIN result_release r ON i.type= r.type
 WHERE 
   (
     t.testtime BETWEEN to_date(
       '2022-11-20T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS
'
     ) 
     AND to_date(
       '2022-11-26T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'
     )
   )
), 
finalresults AS (
 SELECT 
   t.place "place", 
   t.stationnr "stationnr", 
   convres(t.result) "convres", 
   t.type "type", 
   t.testtime "testtime"
 FROM 
   tests t 
   INNER JOIN result_testecu_11 tecu ON tecu.testresid = t.testresid 
   INNER JOIN result_pathecu pecu ON pecu.ecuid = tecu.ecuid 
   INNER JOIN result_pathfunc func ON pecu.ecuid = func.ecuid 

 GROUP BY  
   t.place, 
   t.stationnr, 
   t.type, 
   t.testtime
   t.result
) 
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 finalresults 
ORDER BY 
 finalresults.testtime DESC FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: [Database Object Naming Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA):  *A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.*

Comment: `finalresults.testtime` should be `finalresults."testtime"` as you are using quoted identifiers (which is considered bad practice); or you can remove all the double quotes from the query (which is considered better practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the whole query; that looks like *unfinished* CTE.

Anyway: I presume that culprit is your bad idea of enclosing identifiers into double quotes. `testtime` column is referenced twice, and this looks suspicious:

```
SELECT t.place "place",
       t.stationnr "stationnr",
       convres (t.result) "convres",
       t.TYPE "type",
       t.testtime "testtime"             --> here it is
  FROM tests t
```

As I said: it is unfinished, but - regarding what you said so far - there's the `order by` clause which probably looks like this:

```
select ... 
from finalresults
order by testtime      --> this
```

If you're referencing a column (or alias) whose name is enclosed into double quotes, you have to do that *always*:

```
order by "testtime"
```

In Oracle, that's usually bad idea. Avoid double quotes whenever possible (and that's pretty much always).

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is because you define the column alias:

```sql
finalresults AS (
 SELECT 
   t.place "place", 
   t.stationnr "stationnr", 
   convres(t.result) "convres", 
   t.type "type", 
   t.testtime "testtime"
```

and then refer to it using:

```sql
ORDER BY 
 finalresults.testtime DESC
```

Which does not use the same quoted identifier.

It should be:

```sql
ORDER BY 
 finalresults."testtime" DESC
```

---

However, then you will get onto the next errors as you define:

```sql
WITH tests AS (
 SELECT 
   t.place, 
   t.stationnr, 
   t.result, 
   i.type, 
   t.time,
 FROM
   ...
```

Which is invalid syntax as it has a trailing comma; but ignoring that, you then go on to use:

```sql
finalresults AS (
 SELECT 
   t.place "place", 
   t.stationnr "stationnr", 
   convres(t.result) "convres", 
   t.type "type", 
   t.testtime "testtime"
 FROM 
   tests t 
   ...
```

But your `TESTS` sub-query factoring clause never `SELECT`ed a `testtime` column so you are going to get an error for an invalid identifier.

---

You then have more invalid syntax as:

```sql
 GROUP BY  
   t.place, 
   t.stationnr, 
   t.type, 
   t.testtime
   t.result
```

Is missing a comma between the final two identifiers.

---

What you probably want is to get rid of all the sub-query factoring clauses and just use a single `SELECT`, something like:

```sql
SELECT t.place, 
       t.stationnr, 
       convres(t.result) AS convres, 
       i.type, 
       t.testtime -- or should this be t.time?
FROM   result_test t 
       INNER JOIN result_ident i ON t.place= i.place
       INNER JOIN stat_testplacegroup pg on pg.place = t.place 
       INNER JOIN result_release r ON i.type= r.type
       INNER JOIN result_testecu_11 tecu ON tecu.testresid = t.testresid 
       INNER JOIN result_pathecu pecu ON pecu.ecuid = tecu.ecuid 
       INNER JOIN result_pathfunc func ON pecu.ecuid = func.ecuid 
WHERE  t.testtime BETWEEN DATE '2022-11-20' AND DATE '2022-11-26'
GROUP BY  
       t.place, 
       t.stationnr, 
       i.type, 
       t.testtime, -- or should this be t.time?
       t.result
ORDER BY t.testtime DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```